# Troubling glyphs

Tags: luatex, linux, harftex, luahbtex

To type arabic with the same keyboard layout I used to use on Windows 10, I've created a `.mim` file (key mapping file) and put it in `/usr/share/m17n` to make it work with `ibus-m17n` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based KDE Neon. Everything except the ornated parenthesis, normal parenthesis, braces, brackets and angle brackets works as I expect. Here's my tex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload, fontspec, arabluatex}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
%\setmainfont{Kalpurush}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Al Qalam Quran Majeed Web} 
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}     % Arabic inside LTR
\newcommand{\n}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}     % for digits inside Arabic text
\newcommand{\afootnote}[1]{\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}     % Arabic footnotes
\newenvironment{Arabic}{\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}     % Arabic paragraph
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    \textarabic{﴾وَصِيَّةً﴿ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{(وَصِيَّةً) مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\ 
    \textarabic{\{وَصِيَّةً\} مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{[وَصِيَّةً] مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{<وَصِيَّةً> مِّنَ ٱللّٰه}   
\end{document}
```

Here's what I've got:

[image]

Is it a `harflatex/lualatex` problem or have I missed something in making my keyboard layout? here's how the mapping looks like:

```
;; It's an edited copy of "ar-kbd.mim" file.
(input-method ar phonetic)
(description "Arabic Phonetic (MS Windows).")
(title "ض")

(map
 (arabic
  ("`" "`")
  ("1" "١")
  .
  .
  .
  ("[" "[")
  ("]" "]")
  ("a" "ا")
  .
  .
  .
  ("\(" "\(")
  ("\)" "\)")
  .
  .
  .
  ("{" "{")
  ("}" "}")
  .
  .
  .
  ("<" "<")
  (">" ">")
  .
  .
  .
  ((G-9) "﴾")
  ((G-0) "﴿")
  .
  .
  .
  ((KP_Add) "+")
  ((KP_Subtract) "-")
  )
)

(state
 (init
  (arabic)))
```

I've added the output libreoffice profuced for anyone who knows how to fix those in libreoffice writer.

Comment: Did you mark the paragraph right-to-left in LibreOffice? The output you show would happen if you input Arabic text and a paragraph marked left-to-right.

Comment: Yes! the `pi` with arrow on right solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

arabluatex gets it more or less right. For braces you should according to the documentation use `\abraces`, the ornamental parentheses are intentional not mirrored in Unicode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script = Arabic]
\begin{document}
    \arb{﴾وَصِيَّةً﴿ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \arb{(وَصِيَّةً) مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \arb{\{وَصِيَّةً\} مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \arb{\abraces{وَصِيَّة} مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \arb{[وَصِيَّةً] مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \arb{<وَصِيَّةً> مِّنَ ٱللٰه}
\end{document}
```

[image]

luahblatex with luaotfload 3.11 gets it right too (again with the exception of the ornamental parenthese, which are intentional not mirrored in Unicode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script = Arabic,Renderer=Harfbuzz]
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup} 
\begin{document}
    \textarabic{﴾وَصِيَّةً﴿ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{(وَصِيَّةً) مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{\{وَصِيَّةً\} مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{[وَصِيَّةً] مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{<وَصِيَّةً> مِّنَ ٱللٰه}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with standard luatex it fails, also as luaotfload/the fontloader ignores the bidi-mirrored feature, see https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/61

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script = Arabic]
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup} 
\begin{document}
    \textarabic{﴾وَصِيَّةً﴿ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{(وَصِيَّةً) مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{\{وَصِيَّةً\} مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{[وَصِيَّةً] مِّنَ ٱللّٰه} \\
    \textarabic{<وَصِيَّةً> مِّنَ ٱللٰه}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd a reference to `arabluatex` in the `usepackage` directive, why didn't it work?

Comment: You didn't use it. The command of arabluatex is `\arb` (and it has a quite long documentation, so better check it ...).

Comment: Ornamented parens actually work with arabluatex, one has to use 2 parens instead of 1.

Comment: and to get most out of `arabluatex`, I've to use fonts like `Amiri`. For example `\ayah{11}` doesn't work with the font I used BUT with `Amiri` it does.

Comment: The ornamental parentheses are intentional not mirrored in Unicode, so they should be reversed in the input text, unlike the rest of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

[**Edited**]
[Note: this is not an answer, but a simple additional remark]

This works with standard `luatex`, but LRE, RLE, and PDF Characters (Pop Directional Formatting) have been used.  However, <s>most of the fonts print these marks</s>`luaotfload` has them printed by default (see the screenshot below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script = Arabic]
\begin{document}
\pardir TRT\textdir TRT\arabicfont\noindent
‪﴿‬وَصِيَّةً‪﴾‬ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه\\
‪)‬وَصِيَّةً‪(‬ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه\\
‪\}‬وَصِيَّةً‪\{‬ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه\\
‪]‬وَصِيَّةً‪[‬ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه\\
‪>‬وَصِيَّةً‪<‬ مِّنَ ٱللّٰه\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Printing the BiDi marks is a bug in luaotfload's font loader https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/63

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thank you. My mistake: now I remember that this issue is not a font-related one.  It would be great to be able to have these marks not printed by default while keeping the possibility to print them for testing purposes.